# Calculus deriving functions for a given value

Tags: calculus

$F(x)=x^2-5x+3$. Solve $f'(x)=-1$.

$F (x)=1/x^2$. Calculate $f'(2)$.

I have tried $2x-5=2(-1)-5=-3$ for the first question. The second question I'm not sure of. Explain how these are done not just the answer. Thank you

Comment: I have tried 2x-5=2(-1)-5=-3

Comment: Is f(x) defined? Have you done anything related to the function?

Comment: Please edit it in the post,or the question will be downvoted further and maybe closed. You learn most if you try the question yourself first, and if we can see that.

Comment: Just to be clear, is $f'(x)$ (lowercase f) the derivative of $F(x)$ (capital F)? Usually, if $f$ and $F$ are used in the same question, they denote different functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The first one: The derivative is $f(x)=2x-5$. Solve $2x-5=-1$.

You do not want to put -1 in the function.

The second one, the function is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}=x^{-2}$, thus the derivative is $f'(x)=-2x^{-1}=\frac{-2}{x}$. Now insert 2.

Both derivatives have made use of the power rule, namely that the derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$.